# How can I adjust the height of the cells in a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I used a `box-shadow` to add some depth to the buttons as you can see below, however it 'bleeds' through the gap, and makes the spacing uneven.

[image]

Initially, I tried to change the `grid-template-rows` to account for this:

```
grid-template-rows: calc(1fr - 10px) calc(1fr - 10px);
```

but it didn't seem to do anything.

Minimum code example:

```css
.cont {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
}

.cont>div {
    background: rgb(206, 34, 34);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 rgb(160, 25, 25);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inset shadow:

```css
.cont {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
}

.cont > div {
    background: rgb(206, 34, 34);
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 rgb(160, 25, 25) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! That works perfectly! However, this is just food for thought is there a way to adjust the row height?

Comment: @Coder100 instead of 1fr rely on percentage. Something like calc(50% - 20px) but you have to also account for the gap in the calculation

Answer (score 1):

You could set the row gap and column gap separately:

```css
.cont {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 30px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
}

.cont>div {
    background: rgb(206, 34, 34);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 rgb(160, 25, 25);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```